# Azure API Management with custom authentication sign in, signout, autlogout and custom end points?

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-api-management, azure-authentication, azure-identity

Is this even possible to do below listed tasks using Azure APIM? I have searched through all the documentation of azure apim, tried many policies, tried azure app service, functions and also ms forums too. Cannot find the correct information.

Is there any List Of all options for the authentication Flow of the whole APIM – Login/Logout/AutoLogout/Expiry/Signup URLs?

2- Custom Authentication with custom domains and External non-Azure API's with -> JWT-Validation ->In-bound Service Policy

3- best Possible Options for the Further Authentication Under Azure for the RESTful APIs specifically on-premises on other Cloud e.g. AWS hosted to be controlled through Azure APIM?

Note:- I have tried azure ad oauth2 with client credentials flow already. It worked but only with internal apis for now. the JWT-Validation also worked on Internal APIs only.

Thanks

Comment: please advice what solution did you use for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand all points, but take a look and delegation feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation